# Error! unable to cast object of type 'system.object ' to type 'system.byte[]'

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I Am Trying To Access Data From DataGridView To Form By CellClick Event. In **VB .NET**

When Ever I Click On Cell I Got All Data From Table To Form But Not Able To See Image In **PictureBox**.
 When I Tried Only This Code:

```
 pic1 = selectedRow.Cells(13).Value
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream(pic1)
    pb_stud_pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
```

I Got **Error! unable to cast object of type 'system.object ' to type 'system.byte[]'**

Then I Try Below Code: but Then I Dont Get Image in picture Box..

What I have tried:

```
 Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
        Try

            Dim index As Integer = e.RowIndex
            Dim selectedRow As New DataGridViewRow()
            selectedRow = DataGridView1.Rows(index)

            txt_stud_no.Text = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_name.Text = selectedRow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
            dtp_stud_dob.Value = selectedRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_gender.Text = selectedRow.Cells(3).Value.ToString()

            If txt_stud_gender.Text = "Male" Then
                rdo_male.Checked = True
            Else
                rdo_female.Checked = True
            End If

            cb_stud_blood.Text = selectedRow.Cells(4).Value.ToString()

            txt_stud_add.Text = selectedRow.Cells(5).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_city.Text = selectedRow.Cells(6).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_pc.Text = selectedRow.Cells(7).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_mob.Text = selectedRow.Cells(8).Value.ToString()
            cb_adyear.Text = selectedRow.Cells(9).Value.ToString()
            cb_cbranch.Text = selectedRow.Cells(10).Value.ToString()
            txt_stud_email.Text = selectedRow.Cells(11).Value.ToString()
            cb_csem.Text = selectedRow.Cells(12).Value.ToString()

            con.Open()
            dr = cm.ExecuteReader()
            If dr.Read() Then
                If Not dr.IsDBNull(dr.GetOrdinal("Image")) Then
                    pic1 = CType(dr("Image"), Byte())
                    pic1 = selectedRow.Cells(13).Value
                    pic1 = ds.Tables("Student").Rows(i)(13)

                    If Not (pic1 Is Nothing) Then
                        Dim ms As New MemoryStream(pic1)
                        pb_stud_pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
                    Else
                        pb_stud_pic.Image = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
            End If
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error!" & ex.Message)
            con.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: A DGV cell always returns OBject, but if it is a DataGridViewImageColumn then the value is an Image wrapped in object

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using BinaryFormatter, see on MSDN here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

You will have to Serialize the object into a MemoryStream and call ToArray method on the stream to convert it to byte array and hopefully be able to assign it tho the Image member. Sorry about the lack of code, my VB syntax skills are decades behind.